# How to duplicate a table to itself in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table for example:

```
A   B   C
61  59  6020
101 51  4200
40  36  2440
```

I want to add duplicate values to the table such that the updated table is like this:

```
     A   B   C
    61  59  6020
    101 51  4200
    40  36  2440
    61  59  6020
    101 51  4200
    40  36  2440
```

I only need to increase the size of the table, so the order of the data doesn't matter.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You may insert the entire table into itself:

```sql
INSERT INTO yourTable (A, B, C)
SELECT A, B, C
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: It gives `0 rows updated`

Comment: Run a select after using my answer...you should see twice the number of records.

Comment: I ran a count(*) query and it shows me the exact number of rows it was there previously

Comment: Any primary key or unique constraint issue? Any triggers?